# Geometry proof related to the area of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Show that the area of a quadrilateral ABCD is a quarter of the product of its diagonals if
(i) AB=BC=CD, and
(ii) the mid-point of AD lies on a circle with diameter BC. (There was a typo earlier.)

I've previously seen a solution by constructing a rhombus. However, it looks rather lengthy. I'm wondering if there is a neater solution.

In response to the comments below, below is a sketch of that proof.

Let M be the mid-point of AD. As BMC is a right angle, we can construct a rhombus BCFG with diagonals intersecting at M. It follows that ABDF, ACDG are //grams and ABG, CDF are equilateral.

Let E be the intersection of AC and BD. Using the set up above, it can be deduced that angle AEB=60/2=30. The result then follows.

Comment: I think it should be half instead of quarter.

Comment: You should include the solution you've seen, so that prospective answerers don't duplicate that effort. Besides, how can I tell if my solution is "neater" than one I can't see?

Comment: Are you sure? Something is not true in the given.

Comment: Maybe it should've been the midpoint of BD?

Comment: Oh...it seems there is a hidden assumption that the quadrilateral is convex. You don't get two diagonals for concave quadrilateral.

Comment: @StupidGirl: *(Note to the future: That's OP's rather unfortunate screen name at this point in time.)* Convexity is not a requirement. (Concave quads *certainly* have two diagonals. A diagonal doesn't have to cross a figure's interior.) The half-the-product-of-diagonals-times-sine formula for area works for *any* quadrilateral ... including self-intersecting "bow-tie" quadrilaterals (under an appropriate definition of area for such things).

Comment: @Blue Thanks for teaching me that.

Comment: @Raffaele It seems the same result applies to the concave quadrilateral as well. The diagonals intersect with an angle 30 degrees.